# How to deal with "this" in callbacks?

Tags: javascript

I have a class that is intantiated several times.

```
Captcha = function(el) {
    var _this = this;
    this.el = $(el);
    this.button = this.el.parent().find('button');
    this.render();
};


Captcha.prototype.callback = function() {
    _this.el.addClass('visuallyhidden');
    _this.button.removeClass('visuallyhidden');
};

Captcha.prototype.render = function(grecaptcha){
    this.grecaptcha.render(this.el.dom[0],{
        'sitekey' : 'hash',
        'callback': this.callback
    });
};
```

this.callback references a function that is triggered as a callback on an api-request. As you can see, I try to use _this to reference the function, but _this is not available inside the callback for some reason.

Comment: make your _this global

Comment: replace `this.callback` with `this.callback.bind(this)`

Comment: @S.Petrosov I can't becuase I have more than one instance of the class and the callback needs to know wich one it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can always add objects to the `window` object as a quick storage.

```
Captcha = function(el) {
    var _this = this;
    window.captchaObject = this;
    this.el = $(el);
    this.button = this.el.parent().find('button');
    this.render();
};

Captcha.prototype.callback = function() {
    var _this = window.captchaObject;
    _this.el.addClass('visuallyhidden');
    _this.button.removeClass('visuallyhidden');
};

Captcha.prototype.render = function(grecaptcha){
    this.grecaptcha.render(this.el.dom[0],{
        'sitekey' : 'hash',
        'callback': this.callback
    });
};
```

Comment: I can't becuase I have more than one instance of the class and the callback needs to know wich one.